# Android studio get file path by name

Tags: java, android-studio, file, path

I want to get the full address by the name of the file.
For example:

Input `young_volcanos` - String name

Output `R.raw.young_volcanos` - int path

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getIdentifier()`

```
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("file_name", "raw", this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: wait a sec please